# Is there a relationship between equivalence of norms and compactness?

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, normed-spaces

I was reading between the differences between finite and infinite-dimensional spaces and started thinking about it.
All norms are equivalent in a finite-dimensional space, but this doesn’t hold for infinite-dimensional spaces. Does compactness plays a role in here?

Comment: Is "compacity" compactness?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I’m not a native English speaker.

Comment: There's the theorem that the closed unit ball in a normed space is compact iff the space is finite-dimensional.

Comment: And compactness of the unit sphere for a finite dimensional normed space is the key ingredient in the proof that all norms are equivalent.

Comment: That's an interesting question. Wish I had an interesting answer.